# Pyspark trying connect to spark master, but connection refused

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, cloud, docker-swarm

I have a 3 node docker swarm cluster in cloud, and there are spark master and spark worker services, the spark worker connect to master with success, in spark master UI, is showed the spark worker connection::

[spark master UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyDBH.png)

But there is a service running a python script, with pyspark, the pyspark try connect to spark master, but is showed connection refused error, in logs below:

[pyspark logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmsIR.png)

I used nestat to show the listening ports in cluster, and the port to connection of spark master (7077) is listening:

[listening ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih6MP.png)

I am searching the problem in web for days without response, may help me? thanks.

Comment: Not sure the problem is not clear, that would be greate if you show connection refuse error

Comment: the error log is in pyspark logs, in https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmsIR.png

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile and docker-compose ?

Comment: My docker-compose have sparkmaster and sparkworker service, and projection service running pyspark trying connect to sparkmaster service 
https://github.com/riibeirogabriel/learningOrchestra/blob/feature-preprocessing-projection/docker-compose.yml

Comment: My Dockerfile from sparkworker and sparkmaster image 
https://github.com/riibeirogabriel/learningOrchestra/blob/feature-preprocessing-projection/spark_service/Dockerfile

Comment: I runned curl 0.0.0.0:8080 (spark master UI) in docker exec inside from container running the service with pyspark and have connection refused, but in machine from cluster this port is acessible, i do not understand, the services is in same netwowrk (spark) in docker-compose

Comment: Using the name of service in docker-compose its work, but i not understand why using 0.0.0.0:7077 not work (docker mesh)

Comment: I looked into your docker-compose, I didn't understand how you are using your DBURL, In my knowledge, you need to replace anything whatever you write in you DB URL `root@ ` with `containerName:portNumber`

Answer (score -1):

I looked into your docker-compose. Please try to change your code like this

I removed the other config, just to give you the example.

***Basically what I changed***

Added a new port number `- 27017:27017` provide a container name `container_name: mongoDB` and then the main problem DB URL 
`- DATABASE_URL=mongodb://root:owl45#21@mongoDB:27017/?replicaSet=replica_set #mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<ContainerName:PortNumber>/?replicaSet=replica_set`

```
version: '3'
services:
    database_api:
        build: ./database_api_service
        image: 127.0.0.1:5050/database_api:database_api
        container_name: mongoDB
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
            - 27017:27017
        depends_on:
            - database_primary
            - images
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - "node.role==worker"
        volumes:
            - 'database_api:/database_api'
        networks:
            - database
            - frontend
        environment: 
            - DATABASE_URL=mongodb://root:owl45#21@mongoDB:27017/?replicaSet=replica_set #mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<ContainerName:PortNumber>/?replicaSet=replica_set
            - DATABASE_PORT=27017
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem when connecting to a spark cluster but this answer doesn't address the spark and pyspark parts of the docker setup.  It seems unrelated to spark altogether.